# How to await rxjs Observable without changing all the code to promises

Tags: angular, typescript, asynchronous, async-await, rxjs

Is it possible to await an rxjs observable without changing to Promises?
I am doing 6 requests OnInit() however, some of the requests finish before another, the order matters. Is it possible to await an observable in typescrypt? All functions look the same, they just make a different request to the server.
Thanks for the help :)
Here's my code:

I managed to achieve it by chaining the request( calling next request after I get the response from the previous one, however, that solution was not efficient and looked ugly)

```
 ngOnInit() {
      this.userId = this.auth.getUserId();

      this.getTrendingRentals();
      this.getFollowingRentals();
      ...
      this.getLuxuryRentals();
      //console.log(this.totalRentals);
    }

    private getTrendingRentals() {
        const rentalObservable = this.rentalService.getRentals();
        //Subscribe to service observer
        rentalObservable.subscribe((rentals: Rental[]) => {
          this.trendingRentals = rentals;
          this.totalRentals.push(this.trendingRentals);
        }, (err) => {
        }, () => {
      });
    }


    public getLuxuryRentals(): Observable<any>{
      return this.http.get('/api/v1/rentals/luxury');
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use `switchMap` in the pipe to use the result of the first observable in the subsequent observable.

```
of("Hello").pipe(
            switchMap(result => of(result + ", World")),
            switchMap(result => of(result + "!")),
          )
          .subscribe(console.log);
// output: Hello, World!
```

but if you don't need the result of the previous observable and just want to trigger observables in a specific order, you can use `concat` which waits for every observable to complete before triggering the next observable:

```
concat(
  of(1).pipe(delay(2000)),
  of(2).pipe(delay(500)),
  of(3).pipe(delay(1000))
)
.subscribe(console.log);

// output: 1 2 3
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer!! how of(2).pipe(delay(500)), finishes after of(1).pipe(delay(2000)) even when the delay is smaller?

Comment: `concat` waits for the first observable to complete before triggering the next observable. so the order of putting observable into the `concat` function is relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Methods that are fetching data shouldn't return subscriptions but return observables,

```
private getTrendingRentals() {
    return this.rentalService.getRentals();
}
```

rxjs provides few functions to address this kind of problem. Take a look at functions: `merge`, `mergeMap`, `switchMap`, `concatMap`.

For example:

```
this.auth.getUserId().pipe(
      mergeMap(userId => this.getTrendingRentals()),
      mergeMap(trendingRentals => this.getFollowingRentals()),
      mergeMap(followingRentals => this.getFollowingRentals()),
      mergeMap(luxuryRentals => this.getLuxuryRentals())
).subscribe(...)
```

or

```
this.auth.getUserId().pipe(
      mergeMap(userId => this.getTrendingRentals()),
      mergeMap(trendingRentals => merge(this.getFollowingRentals(), this.getFollowingRentals(), this.getLuxuryRentals()))
).subscribe(...)
```

Dependence on your particular needs.

Update:
@jcal solution with `concat` looks better :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! I am getting confused with this lines 
this.auth.getUserId().pipe(
      mergeMap(userId => this.getTrendingRentals()),
userId is the result of the first function? like a normal callback? I'm new to rxjs so I am just assuming.

Comment: merge doesnt really belong in that list